# How to insert if not exist illuminate slim framework

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder, illuminate-container

I use slim framework and use [illuminate/database](https://github.com/illuminate/database).

I would like to insert data which not duplicate function_number but if different product_id function_number can be duplicate, for example

[image]

here is my mode

```
$app->post('/create_function', function($request, $reponse, $args) {
   $query = $this->db->table('functions')->insert([
            'project_id' => $request->getParam('project_id'),
            'function_number' => $request->getParam('function_number'), 
            'function_text' => $request->getParam('function_text'),
            'created' => date('Y-m-d')
         ]);
   if($query) {
     echo "Function was created";
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your request you want that the couple `(project_id, function_number)` be unique. To do so, you need to query your DB as follows:

```
//Check for duplicate  
$exists = $this->db->table('functions')->where('project_id', '=', $request->getParam('project_id'))->where('function_numbe', '=', $request->getParam('function_number'))->exists();

if(!$exists) {
    //Your insert code here 
}
```